# How does MSE do live previews of MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

How does MSE do live previews of MathJax? I need this for my own site.

I am not a JavaScript developer but I can copy / paste some code into the right place. I'm using [Bubble](https://bubble.is/home) to create a learning site similar to DuoLingo, but for mathematics.

Here is the app:
[MathLing](https://mathling.bubbleapps.io/)

Comment: Right now I have a preview button that works.  It displays a popup.  This should be fine as the majority of users will not necessarily edit content.  But I will leave this here in case anyone has insights into this.

Comment: We have a local group working at the CS department developing their own web-based learning environment. I have been involved with testing and using it. A colleague and I asked for TeX-support, and told them how well MathJax works here. So they contacted MathJax and got a version of the code to run on their website. I don't know exactly how the code is running, but it sounded to me that they got a license. They told me that the people at MathJax were very helpful. May be you can also just ask people at MathJax, and discuss your options?

Comment: Do you mind sharing your objective with MathLing? DuoLingo appears to be a general platform for learning foreign languages but your MathLing site appears to be the very beginnings of a discussion forum. Are you trying to recreate the math.stackexchange experience on your own forum? If so to what end?

Comment: @MarkMcClure no, not an MSE, a duolingo type learning site.  I just began, it!  It shouldn't look like any thing yet, lol!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

StackExchange does something more complicated than you probably need. Their preview functionality is contained in the javascript scripts that they source (creating a StackExchange object). They do all sorts of nice clever things --- and if you want to understand it fully, you can read the javascript source.

But I think you would probably be fine with using something like [this](http://bandicoot.maths.adelaide.edu.au/MathJax/test/sample-dynamic-2.html) --- which I found after a quick search engine and choosing the top hit. The code there is pretty straightforward and copy-able.

---

Aside: I tried to decide if I thought this was on-topic here. I would say it's borderline on-topic, but probably on the off-topic side of the border. If you have further programming questions, the appropriate place to ask them is on one of the programming sites on the network, such as StackOverflow.